# Ruby on Rails: Searching with a boolean - postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, boolean

I have an app that allows users to enter, edit and search for projects in a database.

In my search function, you can do complex searches by adding params to the search.

```
def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_archive, search_client, search_status, search_fullname)
    # start with a scoped query, to apply more scopes on it afterwards
    _projects = Project.scoped 
    # then, for each of the parameters, apply the scope only if present

    if search_archive.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['archive LIKE ?', like(search_archive)] 
    end
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end

     if search_status.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['status LIKE ?', like(search_status)]
    end

if search_fullname.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['fullname LIKE ?', like(search_fullname)]
    end
    # now you have applied only the present scopes. return the result, and watch 
    # the query as it executes.

    _projects

  end
```

Now I recently added the option to archive the project, that goes into the project table as a boolean.

I know my search function is wrong as I don't think I can deal with booleans they way I have tried.

```
if search_archive.present?
          _projects = _projects.where ['archive LIKE ?', like(search_archive)] 
        end
```

Here is the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE (archive LIKE '%{"{:c...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Changing to the suggestion below,

```
if search_archive.present?
  _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive)
end
```

I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "archive"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE "archive"."{:class=>"...
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE "archive"."{:class=>""archive""}" = '1'
```

**Here is my search action:**

```
def search


    @search = params[:archive], params[:client], params[:status], params[:fullname]

    @project_search = Project.search(*@search).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

    @search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty? 

  @project = Project.new(params[:project])


respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

**ADDING PART OF SEARCH VIEW**

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>

<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
Archive:
<%= check_box :archive, :class => "archive" %></H2>
<% end %>
<% if !current_user.try(:admin?) %>
<%= hidden_field :archive, :value => false %>
<% end %>

<div class="client">
Client : 
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.order("client").map{|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<div id="search_button">
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :class => "button" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**EXPLANATION**

If I am an Admin, and I leave the archive check box unchecked, I want to see all projects that aren't archived. If I check it, I only want to see the archived ones, included with other params I search on.

If I am a normal user, I shouldn't be able to see the archive checkbox, and every search I do should be on projects that have archive false, behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `archive` is Boolean add something like follwing

```
if search_archive.present?
  _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive != "false")
end
```

Change

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
Archive:
<%= check_box :archive, :class => "archive" %></H2>
<% end %>
<% if !current_user.try(:admin?) %>
<%= hidden_field :archive, :value => false %>
<% end %>
```

To

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  Archive: <%= check_box_tag :archive, true, false, :class => "archive" %></H2>
<% else %>
  <%= hidden_field :archive, :value => false %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have added my search view. I need to search on either true or false depending on if the user is admin or not.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working. However, I need every search to always search `archive` as false, unless the box is ticket. So that why only admin can see the archived files, and none admin would never seem them, since every search they do always searches `archive` as false

Comment: Just change to  `_projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive == "true")`

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. To make it a bit clearer, I have updated my question at the bottom to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: just remove your if condition for the search and i think it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have kept the IF statement but moved the hidden field so that I always searches false unless stated otherwise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `archive` is a boolean, and you want to search for either true or false on it, and `search_archive` is also a boolean, this is all you need to do:

```
if search_archive.present?
  _projects = _projects.where(:archive => search_archive)
end
```

UPDATE:

Your checkbox syntax is wrong, needs to be something like:

`check_box("project", "archive", {:class => 'archive'})`

Comment: Hi there, I still get an error. I have updated my question with the error, and my search action. Thanks

Comment: Check what you are passing as search_archive variable, it is not boolean.

Comment: It seems that for true, it is passing `1`. But that seems to be ok in postgres?